# Reusable Function Code For Same-Named Objects From Different Namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write 'wrapper' code for two web services that have different namespaces, but contain classes with the same name and definition in each.  I would like to write some function code that I could use in wrapper classes for each web service without simply copying the code into each of them.  For instance, to return an object by name from each:

```
using WebSvc1;
WrapperClassWS1
{
 // The root class inherits from System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
  WebSvc1Root _Root = new WebSvc1Root;

  public MyNonWSobj GetObjectByName(string WhichName)
  {
    // Uses GetWS1ObjectByName to retrieve the 'real' object
    //   then turns that into my dumbed down object for use
    //   by calling code that knows nothing about web services
    // Identical code to WrapperClassWS2
    MyNonWSobj myObj = new MyNonWSobj();
    CommonObj returnedObj = this.GetWS1ObjectByName(string WhichName);
    myObj.Name = returnedObj.Name;
    myObj.Revision = returnedObj.Revision;
    myObj.Description = returnedObj.Description;
    return myObj;
  }

  private CommonObj GetWSObjectByName(string WhichName)
  {
    // Identical code to WrapperClassWS2
    // This function will get an object native to the WebSvc1Root and
    //   the retrieved object will have identical name/definition to
    //   one from WebSvc2Root
    return _Root.getObject(WhichName);
  }
}

using WebSvc2;
WrapperClassWS2
{
 // The root class inherits from System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
  WebSvc2Root _Root = new WebSvc2Root;

  public MyNonWSobj GetObjectByName(string WhichName)
  {
    // Uses GetWS2ObjectByName to retrieve the 'real' object
    //   then turns that into my dumbed down object for use
    //   by calling code that knows nothing about web services
    // Identical code to WrapperClassWS2
    MyNonWSobj myObj = new MyNonWSobj();
    CommonObj returnedObj = this.GetWS1ObjectByName(string WhichName);
    myObj.Name = returnedObj.Name;
    myObj.Revision = returnedObj.Revision;
    myObj.Description = returnedObj.Description;
    return myObj;
  }

  private CommonObj GetWSObjectByName(string WhichName)
  {
    // Identical code to WrapperClassWS1
    // This function will get an object native to the WebSvc2Root and
    //   the retrieved object will have identical name/definition to
    //   one from WebSvc1Root
    return _Root.getObject(WhichName);
  }
}
```

**EDIT2:** The functions that return the CommonObj type from each web service do not need to be named differently in the two wrapper classes.  GetWSObjectByName code was not identical due to _Root variable initialization there.  Fixed code above.

**EDIT1:** Fixed errors in paragraph below and added example code above.

In my real-life case, the CommonObj classes are named the same and have the same definitions in both web service name spaces.  The functions to get the web service objects have the same name and definition, but the class definitions containing the 'get web service object' functions have different names.  I would really like to have only one definition each for both GetObjectByName and GetWSObjectByName.

I thought about just using one class and defining module level variables for the objects from each web service, then setting them to namespace-specific objects.  That would probably keep much of the code common, but I haven't tried it.  (I admit this kind of crazy approach is rooted in VB6 experience where it's a fairly common practice).

To be sure I'm clear:  I have written working code for the first web service.  I could have the same working code for the second web service by simply copying all code from the first wrapper class to a new class, then changing the 'using' statement, class name, and the type of the module level variable representing the web services root class.  That would solve today's problem while setting the stage for tomorrow's problem.

**EDIT:** I had the wrong data type on the _Root2 variable.

**EDIT:** The search for clarity continues... I am not writing the web services and I have no real input on how they are constructed.  I am trying to 'wrap' existing web services in some code I can use with calling code/projects that will have no knowledge of, or reference to the web services.

Comment: does your wsdl to poco generator generate partial classes?

Comment: I'm finding your question unclear, without a good [mcve] that clearly illustrates your scenario. What are the private `Get...ObjectByName()` methods actually _doing_? Namespaces are only a way to organize your types; if the code in each of your implementations is in fact _literally_ identical, I see no reason that there needs to be a copy in each namespace. If it's not literally identical, what difference does in fact exist?

Comment: @DanielA.White: Sorry, that is over my head!

Comment: Based on your example I can't possibly see a reason for two different Types for the _Root field, I also can't see a reason for the _Root fields to be called two different names (_Root1 and _Root2).  You can't share the logic properly this way.

Comment: @KyleB: You are correct - I only need _Root in both, not _Root1 and _Root2.  Got carried away, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
// An abstract class for shared code
abstract class WrapperClassWS<T> // T enables generics on your abstract class
{
    private abstract T _Root { get; } // _Root is now of type 'T' (a generic type)

    public MyNonWSobj GetObjectByName(string WhichName)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private CommonObj GetWSObjectByName(string WhichName)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// Implementation of WS1 wrapper
class WrapperClassWS1 : WrapperClassWS<WebSvc1Root>
{
    override WebSvc1Root _Root 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return ...; // return root for this namespace
        } 
    }        
}

// Implementation of WS2 wrapper
class WrapperClassWS1 : WrapperClassWS<WebSvc2Root>
{
    override WebSvc2Root _Root 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return ...; // return root for this namespace
        } 
    }        
}
```

Edit: I added generics to the abstract class so now the implemented type can be of two different _Root classes.

If you want to share logic and code, you're going to need to keep some stuff the same, I edited my example with generics so you can make the _Root variable two different Types but you can't really call the variable '_Root1' and '_Root2' if you want to share the logic unless the Roots are fundamentally different variables and will be used in different ways.
You may want to look into the SOLID Principles of programming.  The SOLID principles can give you some clues on how to effectively share logic and separate portions of your programming so that you are not writing code that is hard to manage later on.

Comment: In the abstract class, which namespace is the CommonObj class coming from?  Also, I made a critical mistake in my original example - the root class names are different in the two web services.

Comment: Your answer is full of things unfamiliar to me and pretty much over my head given my current knowledge level, but I decided to take a shot at it anyway.  To my surprise, this seems like it has a chance of working.  In the abstract class' 'GetWSObjectByName' function, I'm getting errors that the 'T' type does not contain a definition for the getObject function (added sample code to my original post).  I should mention that I'm using .NET 3.5 - for no good reason, and that can easily be changed. I'm also looking at an approach using 'dynamic' so .NET 4+ may be a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to duplicate some code, but you can minimize the duplication.  I would recommend creating an interface that encapsulates the essential behaviors of each service.  For example:

```
interface IService {
    MyNonWSobj GetObjectByName(string WhichName)
}
```

For each service, you will need to create a class that implements this interface somehow.

```
public class ServiceA : IService {

    public MyNonWSobj GetObjectByName(string WhichName)
    { 
        //Do stuff 
    }

    private CommonObj GetWS1ObjectByName(string WhichName)
    {
        //Some private implementation stuff 
    } 
}
```

However, any code that needs to use services and do more complex operations with them can just reference `IService` and it will then be compatible with either service.

```
public void DoSomethingInterestingWithAService(IService service, string name) {
    var obj = service.GetObjectByName(name);

    DoSomethingCool(obj);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the bulk of the code in my wrapper classes would fall under the 'private implementation stuff' category.  And that's all of the complicated code I'd rather not duplicate just to work with the two web services.